# how to calling a form element and save the data

Tags: forms, cakephp, element

I have made controllers and models  for post and comment.

I've made my post index calling my add comment view. It works fine but the add comment view open another page.

Then, I have included the add comment view into an element in order to call directy into my post page but when I click to the submit button of my comments add view, it does not save anything.

When I look at the link displayed by the submit button  it points to my post index view.

How to make it works ?

Here is the code of my comment element

```
div class="comments form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Comment'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Comment'); ?></legend>
    <?php


        $this->request->data['Comment']['user_id'] = $current_user['id'];
        $this->request->data['Comment']['post_id'] = $post_id;

        echo $this->Form->input('post_id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
        echo $this->Form->input('user_id', array('type' => 'hidden'));

        echo $this->Form->input('content');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

here is part of the code of index post view calling that element

```
<div class="element">
        <?php echo $this->element('add_comment', array('post_id' => $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
        </div>
```

I must add that this div class element is inside a clickable div. But the click works fine for other button I have in the view.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the url of the form to direct it to the add action in Comments controller like this

```
echo $this->Form->create('Comment', array(
    'url' => array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'add')
));
```

By default, if you don't pass the url` parameter, the form points to the current action been rendered (in this case, the post controller), so you need to specify where you want it to post. Check [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-create) to read about that option.